# NSUNS3: How to start with more characters?

Tags: naruto-ultimate-ninja-storm-3

I've heard that you can start with more characters in Naruto Shippuden: Ultimate Ninja Storm 3. Is this true? If it is, how is it done?

Comment: Doesn't anyone know how to do this? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To start the game with extra characters, you have to play the game while using a system that has save files of the other Ultimate Ninja Storm games (1, 2, and Generations). There is a **wide** variety of people you can unlock, ranging from Naruto to Minato Namikaze.